# What is orthogonal group $O(1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

I know that $O(2)$ is the group of 2x2 orthogonal matrices, but how can we extend the meaning of group and orthogonal to $O(1)$?

Comment: It's the group of $1 \times 1$ orthogonal matrices. There are two of these, namely $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: What are some of the utility for this group?

Comment: You can use it as a base case in some inductive arguments involving the orthogonal groups.

Comment: @FemaleTank: Trivial cases are important for many reasons in mathematics, so watch out for them! As Qiaochu’s comment suggests, they provide a basis for induction; they are often good extreme test cases for a hypothesis or to check your reasoning; sometimes they suggest insights you might generalise (though they are just as often misleading!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a\in\mathbb{R}^1$, $a\cdot a^T=1\Longrightarrow a^2=1\Longrightarrow a=\pm 1$. So $O(1)=\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: what are some utilities of this group?

Comment: The group $O(1)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2$ has [fantastic properties](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/148925/fantastic-properties-of-z-2z).